# Imprecisão do resultado de soma de coluna

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ambiente: Excel 2013
Exemplo: Ao somar os valores de uma coluna com 1110 linhas, o resultado obtido é 302.204.548,38
Se acrescentar o valor de 249.998,78 da linha 1111 da mesma coluna, deveria obter 302.454.547,16 mas em vez deste valor o resultado é 302.454.547,159999

Alguém me pode ajudar a ultrapassar esta imprecisão?
Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

António Jesus

Answer (score 2):

Olha, isso na verdade não é um bug, mas uma característica de como os números em ponto flutuante (com casas decimais) são armazenados e operados na memória dos computadores.

Como os números são codificados em binário e tem uma precisão limitada, há números fracionários que não tem um correspondente exato em binário. Quando o valor resultante de uma operação matemática resulta em um desses números, aparece uma diferença que não existiria na matemática "lápis e papel" em base 10.

Um exemplo bem mais simples que o seu seria:

```
   =1*(0,5-0,4-0,1)
```

Digite isso em qualquer célula do Excel e você vai receber um valor bem pequeno, mas diferente de 0, que seria o esperado.

A Microsoft tem dois artigos explicando isso e sugerindo correções:

- [KB78113](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/78113)
- [KB214118](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/214118)